# HTML - Can I have an iframe inside an image and make it responsive?

Tags: html, image, iframe, video, responsive-design

Been trying to figure this out, but I don't seem to get the hang of this.

I am trying to get a video to play inside this laptop image. I want to get the image and the video to both be responsive as browser size changes.

Can anyone help???

```
<div id="tvBorder" style="background-image: url('http://www.ninasalon.co.uk/images/testing.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:625px; height:532px; padding:80px;">

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/125108525?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="517" height="298" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="margin-left:14px;margin-top:-27px;"></iframe>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to post some more information about what you mean when you say "responsive". Do you want this to scale variably with the page width? Do you want it to change at a certain page width?

Comment: I think you will need some javascript and check the screen size whenever the user changes it, so you can resize your elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `vw` unit to scale the dimensions based on the width of the viewport.

You will need to adjust the following numbers to get it to fit but here is the general idea:

CSS

```
div {
    background-image: url('http://www.ninasalon.co.uk/images/testing.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width:62.5vw;
    height:53.2vw;
    padding:8vw;  
}

iframe {
    width:51.7vw;
    height:29.8vw;
    margin-left:1.4vw;
    margin-top:2.7vw;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="tvBorder">

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/125108525?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle that shows it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/c5zrny2d/)